# Android Virtual Device(AVD) creation issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create AVD in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I am using Android Studio. While i'am going to create AVD it showing "An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details". I couldn't found anything at log file.

Last few line generated at log file while creating AVD:

```
2017-03-10 11:27:01,806 [ 204460]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2017-03-10 11:28:42,656 [ 305310]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Initializing adb using: /home/hizbul/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb, client support = true 
2017-03-10 11:28:46,759 [ 309413]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Successfully connected to adb 
2017-03-10 11:28:46,763 [ 309417]   INFO - ditor.DeployTargetPickerDialog - Successfully obtained debug bridge 
2017-03-10 11:30:39,268 [ 421922]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create the SD card. 
2017-03-10 11:30:39,268 [ 421922]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder. 
2017-03-10 11:31:19,319 [ 461973]   INFO - .script.IdeScriptEngineManager - javax.script.ScriptEngineManager initialized in 642 ms
```

Comment: Have you looked at the log file by going to _Show Log in Files_ under Android Studio's _Help_ menu?  If you can try the AVD creation again, and then post the last few lines of that file, it would be helpful.

Comment: Updated with the logfile data.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,AndroidStudio 2.*,Using this:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

It works.

Comment: try add sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386 as per https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Comment: New 16.04 installation today and this worked for me after trying various other fixes

Comment: Thank you this fixed the issue for me

Comment: Works for Android 3 on ubuntu 17.10 too

Comment: Worked for Android Studio 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Works for Android Studio 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 18.04